# Why iOS ad-hoc distribution still need to trust enterprise developer?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

We have an enterprise account and need to distribute the App with ad-hoc distribution.

But with  the ad-hoc distribution, the testers were still  asked to `trust enterprise developer` and we cannot find the `profile & device management` in the Setting. Why does  iOS ad-hoc distribution still need to trust enterprise developer?

Is there anyone who encountered the similar issue?

Comment: I already filed a TSI for this because I can't wrap my head around it. Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: Hi IBG, the story was long time ago. I filed a TSI to Apple and proven that they do not know the exact reason about this issue, but we get problem solved. There are two ways you can make it. 1. Upgrade your OS to newer version or Reset your device 2. Send a TSI and communicate with the staff in Apple, they can access your provision files and certifications, I don't know what they did, I guess they reset my certification or provision file and the `profile & device management` show up, though the staff did not explain very well of the reason.

Comment: Let us know when you got the reason and solution, answer below, I will take it as the right answer. This is a really annoying problem and waste me a lot of time. Hope the answer will benefit others who encountered similar case.

Comment: I will. They responded and have me doing additional steps so they know which support team to send me. For now our work-around is to just distribute the application as in-house. I will update and possibly add the answer if I get any.

Answer (score 0):

```
Once you installed application, 

1: Go to setting -> General
2: Profile and Device Management 
3: Click on "Untrusted app"
4: There is option for "trust"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that on my iPad `Setting` -> `General` we cannot find `Profile` existed. Actually, with ad-hoc distribution, you don't need to trust the enterprise developer right?

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7611217 , the "profile and device management" setting only shows up when a profile has been installed. If it is not showing up it means the tester did not install the profile.

The ad-hoc requires the user to trust it because it has not gone through the apple approval process. This is a security feature to make sure users are not installing random, potentially malicious apps on their phones. Its meant to make them aware that this isn't a verified app yet and they need to be sure they trust the person who sent it to them

Comment: The ad-hoc should not require the user to trust, because there's a set list of devices in the account. It means that the device is recognized as a test device, and is different from the "in-house" release. Besides, the profile is not showing up. That is the main issue.

We experimented around this issue, and found that installing the in-house along with the ad-hoc build allows us a workaround because the certificate shows up in that case. We also analyzed the ad-hoc ipa and sure enough, the profile is included in the build. So the question is, why is it not showing?

Comment: @IBG I'm not sure why its not showing under the "profile and device management" section. But my understanding is ad-hoc or not, if it comes from an enterprise account, it needs to be trusted by the user as an extra layer of security. I'm not sure how you are installing it, but I know tools like hockey app doing over the air installing typically install the profile first and then the app. It could be an issue in your setup that the profile is inside the bundle, but not being installed separately before the app downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue since 3 weeks. After xcode 9.3 update, I couldn't run ad-hoc build on the device with enterprise account. It was asking to trust developer on settings but you don't need to trust developer on ad-hoc build, you just need to add device uuid to provision profile. Also there is not an option about it on device management section on settings, if ipa file was generated via ad-hoc distribution.

I tried with newly generated ad-hoc provision profile but there was no luck. I tried newly created project with new app id and still no luck.

I think there are some changes about ad-hoc distribution on enterprise account or some bugs.

I used company account to export ad-hoc build to workaround the issue.